# Is it possible to create asynchronous web services in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asynchronous

I am not looking to be able to call web services asyncronously, I can already do that. What I want is to be able to create an asynchronous web service in a similar manner that I can create an asynchronous web page using the AddOnPreRenderCompleteAsync method.

I have a web service that is dependent on another web service. I wish to be able to rewrite my web service is such a way that it releases the worker/IO threads to process other requests whilst the call to the external web service completes and then attaches to another worker/IO thread to complete the processing much like the asynchronous page example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx

I cannot however find any references to this being available for web services (or more specifically, nothing similar is available for web services) within ASP.NET

I am using ASP.NET 2.0/3.5

Answer (score 2):

Did you search on MSDN?

- [How to: Create Asynchronous Web Service Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb559019.aspx)
- [How to: Chain Asynchronous Calls with a Web Service Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552886.aspx)
- [MSDN Search: "asynchronous web services"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/?Refinement=-112%2c-108%2c-109&Query=asynchronous+web+service)

---

### Note

Notice the part where they say:

> This topic is specific to a legacy
>   technology. XML Web services and XML
>   Web service clients should now be
>   created using [Windows Communication
>   Foundation (WCF)].